# Submodule ref problem in cloning master project

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

We have a master project witch use submodule. We merged Master project branch into master project and this branch contained some submodule changes, and this changes not applied into submodule master. Now we cant do anything to master project because it contains ref, but submodule has not. Exception then we clone master project: Fetched in submodule path 'submodule', but it did not contain 05sdfssdfwe234324544911. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
How we can resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like the submodule changes has not been pushed to the server, either that or they have been overwritten by a force push that removed/changed the commit in question.

Comment: but how can i resolve that?
Do i need to make changes in submodule and then update master project?

Comment: Make change in submodule repo, push the change - then update and push your master repo. And never, ever, force push to overwrite changes in your submodule repo